# NullPointerException while scrolling gallery widget

Tags: android, gallery, nullpointerexception

I have a strange error (NullPointerException) ocurring sometimes while using gallery widget, it occurs only sometimes when scrolling fast in different directions - what is strange, there's none of my classes in the stack trace.

does anyone have any idea what could cause the problem?

```
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6906)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6906)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6906)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1868)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
10-05 11:54:45.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should show your code, what you have tried to do.

Comment: It's quite a big project already - the gallery i'm using is actually extending the gallery widget, I use lazy loading for images in a seperate thread and lots of code that could cause the problem... but how can I know what's causing it if none of my classes is listed in the stack trace? I don't even know what parts of the code could i post here...

Comment: OK no problem, The problem with Bitmap API is there, it throughs null the the size of the Bitmap exceeds to some limit that might be the issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens sometime. It happened with me as well. I wasn't able to find the root cause but what I did as a solution was to wrap the code with try catch and using a !null check solved my problem.

Comment: Which part of your code did you wrap with try/catch - if you don't even know what caused the error? If I knew where the error starts I probably could find a solution (or at least try).

Comment: yes this isnt the exact way to solve errors but I needed to get away from this error that time so I used this approach. Actually this error doest occurs every time it happens sometime so I did this and to handle it.

Comment: @imbryk You can use LogCat to trace on which line number the exception is occurring.